# Drupal nested subform

Tags: forms, drupal, content-management-system, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I'm working on a directory service using Drupal where each place has more than one branch, I need to create the content type (branches) and be able to add branches using the same form of adding a directory item.

Is there a module that helps me in doing is (if it's Ajax that would be excellent).

Answer (score 0):

If branches are related to directories via node reference (cck), you can use the [node relationships module](http://drupal.org/project/noderelationships) to add branches via a popup window while adding directories.